# Lily asked very excited

Tags: phrase-meaning, parts-of-speech

The full context is

> "I'm so awfully glad, Jimmy. You want some more, don't you?" Lily asked very excited.

Let's pick out a sentence

> Lily asked very excited.

Why is this sentence correct? What is the function of *excited* in this sentence?

If it is an adjective then we should write

> Very excited Lily asked.

If it is a participle then we should write

> Lily asked being very excited.

If it is an adverb then we should write

> Lily asked very excitedly.

Comment: Where did you find this? It is not a complete sentence; it looks as though it should follow Lily's question, and there would normally be a comma after _asked_.

Comment: I found it in an old text-book. You are right it is not a full sentence. I added the full one to my question. There is no comma after _asked_. But what whould change if comma would have been?

Comment: No, it's not an adverb. "Very excited" is an adjective phrase functioning as a predicative adjunct with "Lily" as predicand. Compare the predicative complement in "Lily was very excited". A comma before the phrase would be helpful, but not essential.

Comment: So, "Very excited Lily asked"="Lily asked very excited" ? Isn't there difference between the sentences excepting the sequence of words?

Comment: The first sentence in your latest comment isn't grammatical. I can't even come to explain what it means. Like it could come out as a question, if a question mark is placed after _excited_, and a comma after it.

Comment: "Lily asked" follows Lily's words to show who said them. The author adds _very excited_ to describe her manner as she was speaking. _Very excitedly_ could have been used instead. The inverted version would only work if it was placed before the speech. "Very excited, Lily asked 'You want some more, don't you?'"

Comment: Your source text isn't orthographically reliable. ***No*** "authority" on English would accept ***very excited*** it without the comma, though I personally wouldn't be so dogmatic about rejecting comma-less ***very excitedly***, which is a whole nother syntactic ball game.

Answer (score 1):

There really ought to be a comma after “asked”; it reads very badly without, and I would argue is unacceptable.

> Lily asked, very excited.

This simply means she was very excited when she asked.

You could use this form for all kinds of things, e.g.:

> Lily asked, holding a pen.

You could perhaps think of the comma as being a substitute for the word “while”.

So, for example:

> Lily asked while holding a pen.

> Lily asked while very excited.

Using “while” doesn’t read quite as well, especially in the “excited” example, as it gives equal emphasis to both parts (the asking and the excitement), so the comma form sounds better in my opinion - it makes the asking part much more prominent, which is generally how it should be in this speaking context.

Comment: The comma is not essential, though preferred. "Very excited" and "holding a pen" do not have the same function. The former is an AdjP with "Lily" as predicand, while "holding a pen" is a clause functioning as a temporal adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ Exactly. As I said, you can use this form for many things. Generally speaking, both phrases are describing something about Lily’s state as she speaks.